# MongoDB: How to multiply an Array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, multiplication

**My Query:**

```
db.Customer.aggregate([{"$group":{"_id":"$CustNum", "CustName":{"$first":"$CustName"}, "TransDate":{"$first":"$TransactionDate"},"ProdDesc":{"$first":"$ProdDesc"}, "Price":{"$first":"$Price"}, "QTY":{"$first":"$QTY"} } }, {"$project":{"Total":{"$multiply":["$QTY", "$Price"]} }}  ])
```

My Error:

```
uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "$multiply only supports numeric types, not array",
        "code" : 16555,
        "codeName" : "Location16555"
```

Is there any way to Multiply an Array in mongoDB? or Should I update it make it as a Number instead of an Array?

Comment: When you post a question, you need to post sample simplified documents also... Otherwise who can we  check?

Comment: And you need to explain the problem what you facing and what your are trying to!!

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to multiply the value under the key "Price" by the value under the key "QTY". We can see that these values were in your original documents but we don't know what were their types. The error suggest that the value of one of them (at least) is not a number, but an array. If you provide a sample data, we can easily see the values before the multiplication attempt. If you want to multiply a number by an array of numbers, you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71829529/compound-interest-mongodb-query).