# Compound Interest MongoDB Query

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, quantitative-finance

Trying to calculate compound interest in my aggregation query.

I have created this array of weekly return factors, and assuming a starting value of $100

```
{

"investThis": 100,

"wklyReturns" : [ 
        0.953268776798189, 
        1.00703473704638, 
        0.994451681381773, 
        1.05357596706145, 
        0.99028490888956, 
        0.981037037037037, 
        1.01519025417356, 
        0.990515443440262, 
        1.01512249218671, 
        1.01603072983355, 
        0.991167064317986, 
        0.919182492650833, 
        0.991854491599945, 
        0.971319397617442, 
...
]

}
```

All need to do is multiply "investThis" by index 0 return factor, then reuse the result and multiply that by index 0+1 return factor, all the way down the weeklyReturns list.

Here are a couple screenshots from google sheet calculation...

[start drag and drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHcjP.png)

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuEPF.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you need to do is add your aggregation one more step:

```
{
    $project: {
      "results": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$wklyReturns",
          initialValue: "$investThis",
          in: {
            $multiply: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

As you can see on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/myDv7N9AJ_r).
The `$reduce` operation allows you to repeat an action each time using the previous result.

Comment: That's it! Down to the penny!

I can' thank you enough, cheers 